# Wordpress sidebar drop down for Ambience theme

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, sidebar

I used WooCommerce plugin with Storefront Wootheme. When I transferred to Ambience theme I found sidebar drop down, although the sidebar in the first theme worked well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: i found the reason of the problem but i can't solve it the reason is canvas of product display area very large, so the sidebar was down please help

Comment: why no one want to help me in this site this second Q and no one help me ? what's wrong?